# How does HTTP OPTIONS method determine allowed methods in IIS 8.5?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I'm looking to remove the `TRACE` method from my web site in IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter).  I have implemented this using request filtering as below:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
        <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false" />
      </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This prevents `TRACE` requests, but if I send an `OPTIONS` request, it still lists out `TRACE` in the `Allow` and `Public` headers.  I've reset IIS, but can't get `TRACE` out of `OPTIONS`.  I don't want to deny `OPTIONS`.

This is problematic because it appears that a compliance scan we abide by uses `OPTIONS` as its indicator that `TRACE` is enabled.  I know this is not correct, but that's the criteria I have to meet.

**Is there any way of getting OPTIONS to report the available methods correctly?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question. All the methods to remove `response headers` from IIS don't seem to work for the `Allow` and `Public` headers, an `OPTIONS` request always returns:

```
Allow:  OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
```

regardless what the server actually allows.

All requests in IIS are handled by modules, the `OPTIONS` requests are handled by the `ProtocolSupportModule` which is not essential and as it seems pretty dumb.

If we remove that module, the server doesn't response to Options request anymore, which you still want to support, so we have to use another module to answer those.

Open:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

and search for `OPTIONSVerbHandler` comment that line and while you are at it the one above (`TRACEVerbHandler`) as well. Now add a new node:

```
<add name="MyOPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="StaticFileModule" requireAccess="None" />
```

the whole block should look like this:

```
    <!--  <add name="TRACEVerbHandler" path="*" verb="TRACE" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" /> 
          <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" /> -->
          <add name="MyOPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="StaticFileModule" requireAccess="None" />
```

Now the staticFileModule will process the `OPTIONS` requests but it will not return any content.

If you now make a `OPTIONS` request to the server, you wont get a `Allow` nor a `Public` header, you can add them easily in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <add name="Allow"  value="GET,POST,HEAD" />  
          <add name="Public" value="GET,POST,HEAD" />
      </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>        
</system.webServer>
```

now your `OPTIONS` requests work as required, but those extra headers are also sent with any `GET` or `POST` requests which I think is still valid http.

If you only want to use those headers for `OPTIONS` requests you could write a simple http module that sets these headers and use it instead of the StaticFileModule I used above.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had wondered if the OPTIONS handler needed replacing, your answer gives me a route to handle this.